# Writing to CSV using bash sed not working as expected

Tags: bash, csv, sed

I'm having some trouble getting this code to work, and I have no idea why it's not, Maybe one of you gurus can lend me a hand.

To begin with I have two CSV files structured as such:

**Book1.csv:**

```
Desc,asset,asset name,something,waiver,waiver name,init date,wrong date,blah,blah,target
akdhfa,2014,adskf,kadsfjh,123-4567,none,none,none,none,none,BOOP
```

**Book2.csv**

```
Desc,asset,asset name,something,waiver,waiver name,init date,wrong date,blah,blah,target
akdhfa,2014,adskf,kadsfjh,123-4567,none,none,none,none,none
```

(Lack of "BOOP" on the second book)

What I want is to scan `Book1.csv` for column 11. If it's there, find the matching row in `Book2.csv` based on `asset` and `waiver`. Then simply append the target to that line.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
oldIFS=IFS
IFS=$'\n'
HOME=($(cat Book1.csv))
for i in "${HOME[@]}"
do
    target=`echo $i | cut -d "," -f 11`
    asset=`echo $i | cut -d "," -f 2`
    waiv=`echo $i | cut -d "," -f 5`
    if [ "$target" != "target" ]
    then
        sed -i '/*${asset}*${waiv}*/s/$/,${target}/' Book2.csv
        fi
done
IFS=oldIFS
```

Everything seems to be working except for the sed command. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hm, should those `*`ś be `.*`'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

```
sed -i '/*${asset}*${waiv}*/s/$/,${target}/' Book2.csv
```

which means that the variables are not expanded (the `'` quotes "hide" them).

Also the `*` needs something "in front of it" - probably you meant to use `.*` (otherwise you are looking for "any number of repeats of the last character in `asset`, etc.).

Just change it to

```
sed -i "/.*${asset}.*${waiv}.*/s/$/,${target}/" Book2.csv
```

Now the variables will be replaced with their value before the `sed` command runs, and the quantifier (`*`) should work properly, as it has something to quantify (`.`)...

Comment: Thank you sir! You're a life saver! I knew it was probably something stupid.

Comment: Not really stupid. There are two types of mistakes: the ones you have made, and the ones you are going to make. The best you can do is hope that there are few repeats of type 1... I am most likely a few years ahead of you in the making of mistakes (and learning from them).

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You're using single quotes, which inhibit variable expansion. Change to double quotes.</strike>

This awk might be tidier:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
    NR == FNR {boop[$2,$5] = $11; next}
    NF != 11  {$11 = boop[$2,$5]}
    {print}
' Book1.csv Book2.csv > tmpfile && mv tmpfile Book2.csv
```

awk does not have a `-i` option.

Comment: "target" would be the more logical array name to use.

Comment: Neither double quotes or the awk worked. Using cat and opening the file with excel provided nothing. Could you explain the awk step by step for me please?

Comment: The first line reads Book1 and stores the 11th column in an associative array keyed by the 1st column. The second and third lines are processing Book2, inserting the 11th column based on what was in Book1, only if a line has less than 11 columns. You say excel: are you using cygwin? Do the csv files have `\r\n` line endings?

Comment: Oops, I had the key wrong, you wanted asset and waiver, not desc.